# Is it possible for an I/O callback within a .NET Windows Service that calls C#'s await to not block?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I know that in ASP.NET that the worker thread goes back to the pool when await is used while the I/O happens in the background, which is great for scalability.

My Windows Service is a socket server, and it uses Begin / End style async socket I/O.  Mixing my magic, I know.  I'm in the EndRead callback, receiving a request to do work.  I don't want the thread that made the callback to block.

I'm using the Nito.AsyncEx library, using AsyncContext.Run(() => DoMyBiddingHopefullyInTheBackground(...))...

```
private void EndRead(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int nRead = m_socketStream.EndRead(result);
    ...
    AsyncContext.Run(() => DoMyBiddingHopefullyInTheBackground(...))
}

private async Task DoMyBiddingHopefullyInTheBackground(...)
{
    await DoSomeAsyncIoWork();
}
```

Using AsyncContext was the only way I could find for non-async-marked code to call async-marked code that uses await.

Will AsyncContext.Run block the thread that called my socket End callback routine?  If so, is there any way to make it so that that thread goes back to the thread pool during the async / await I/O?

Comment: I would convert the `BeginRead`/`EndRead` ([APM model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to a task based async/await ([TPM model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) either through using a `ReadAsync` if availalbe or through [`Task.Factory.FromAsync(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why not use Task.Factory.FromAsync and simply turn the Begin/End to an async method?

Comment: From the Nito.AsyncEx doc: "The Run method will return when all asynchronous operations have been completed. Any exceptions will be unwrapped and propagated."

Comment: Scott and 13arnon, I'd like to convert our codebase from Begin / End to async / await, but that's a problem for another day.  Ben, sorry, I'm a little dense and new to this game, so what would conclude from the doc quote w.r.t. the problem I'm asking about?

Comment: @MichaelBalloni: That `AsyncEx.Run` is designed to block.  It's the wrong function for what you are trying to do.  See MailmanOdd's answer for a similar function that does not block (and as a bonus, is part of the .NET Base Class Library and doesn't need an extra library installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an `async` method and you don't want to wait for it to complete, try this:

```
Task.Run(() => DoMyBiddingInTheBackground());
```

Comment: @Scott: No it is not spawning a new thread.  [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) says "Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool"

Comment: Agreed with Ben, it doesn't spawn a new thread. I use this often and it scales just fine.

Comment: How does Task.Run compare with Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncContext.Run?  The sense I've gotten is that the Nito class library handles a lot of details, making my code simpler and the behavior more predictable.  Something about exception handling maybe.  Or should I just ditch the Nito library and use Task.Run?

Comment: I've never heard of the Nito library so I can't really speak to that. The .NET Parallel Task Library performance and usability has always been great in my opinion.

Comment: So I just call Task.Run and it will queue the work on the background, and then my EndRead callback can just fall through to calling BeginRead and reading another request?

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Task.Run just enqueues the call and returns control immediately.  This is okay for my situation...it will make it so that the server can handle much higher requests / second, but the downside is that it may overload the thread pool.  Is there any pushback on Task.Run when too much has been enqueued?  Does my async socket code uses the same thread pool as the task.run does?  Things might grind to a halt then, huh?  Maybe that's the pushback...seems more like denial of service.  Any parting advice?

Comment: Without knowing more about your application, I can't really say what will happen. Sorry!