# What happens when you use Task.Run so much that the thread pool is exhausted?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, threadpool, async-await

I have a .NET Windows Service that implements a socket server using the BeginRead / EndRead async I/O paradigm.  Now this socket code needs to call into some async / Task / await async code.

I had been using the Nito.AsyncEx library's AsyncContext class' Run method, but I had reservations about whether calling that from EndRead would block, holding the worker thread hostage.  The advice I got to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338300/is-it-possible-for-an-i-o-callback-within-a-net-windows-service-that-calls-cs) was to use Task.Run instead of Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncContext.Run.  This submits the call into the async / await code and returns immediately.  It occurred to me that under load that there's no pushback on clients to keep requests from flooding the thread pool.

I'll re-ask my original question about Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncContext.Run: Does it hold the thread it's called on (the pool thread calling my socket's EndRead callback) hostage, or does it free up that thread while the async I/O that it's calling happens in the background?

If Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncContext.Run truly blocks, then Task.Run seems to be my only choice.  Any advice on how to pushback on client requests to prevent thread pool exhaustion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `AsyncContext.Run` is to block until all asynchronous operations have completed. It does hold the thread until that happens.

I suggest you reconsider every assumption so far:

1. Do you really need a socket server? There are **tons** of pitfalls around TCP/IP sockets. Seriously. A **lot** of them. Is there *any* way you can self-host WebAPI instead? It would be a *lot* easier to get working than a socket server.
2. Why do you need to push the work onto a thread pool thread? The `End*` callback is already invoked on a thread pool thread.
3. Are you sure you need to throttle? There is no code that can stop a sufficiently motivated DoS attack.

If you're sure that you do need to implement your own TCP/IP server, and you can't do the work synchronously in your callback, and you do need to throttle... then consider [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) or [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both of those libraries have optional throttling built-in.

Comment: A socket server is a requirement for low overhead for our few and high throughput clients.  We also support HTTP, and that code uses HttpTaskAsyncHandler, so I'm not worried about scalability with that, and that has more clients with lower throughput requirements.  Using AsyncContext.Run wouldn't push back on the client for many of our request types (they do Begin / End of their own...).  My concern about client pushback was unwarranted worry...we're in control of who connects to our socket servers.  Task.Run should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly your application is doing. Here are some scenarios:

**You are processing a stream of data from each client**

The clients each send some data, your server processes each message as it comes in. In this case, there may be no need to run the processing in a separate thread. While you're blocking, the TCP stack is building up a buffer for you to read. If the remaining buffer size is too small, the TCP stack will send a window size warning to the client.

**Clients may send a burst of messages each requiring lengthy processing**

Clients send messages to your server in bursts. Each message requires a considerable amount of time to process. Handling messages in serial would cause lots of TCP retries, and be problematic. In this case, fire off `Task.Run` and don't worry about exhausting the threadpool.

**Clients may send far more data than you can process**

Processing messages from clients is time consuming, and clients may realistically send more work than you can handle. In this case, you may need some kind of application-specific flow control. Perhaps the clients need to poll for server status before sending a message. If clients send anyway, you're forced to disregard the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your TCP/IP insights.  I hadn't thought about it that way.  If we get flooded, we get flooded.  We just need to have enough servers to support our client load.